# How to select only the next smaller value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select smaller number from the database with the SQL.

I have table in which I have records like this

```
ID NodeName NodeType
4  A        A
2  B        B
2  C        C
1  D        D
0  E        E
```

and other columns like name, and type.

If I pass "4" as a parameter then I want to receive the next smallest number records:

```
ID NodeName NodeType
2  B        B
2  C        C
```

Right now if I am using the `<` sign then it is giving me

```
ID NodeName NodeType
2  B        B
2  C        C
1  D        D
0  E        E
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: 1 and 0 are smaller than 4, you just want the *next* smallest record? Why would your records have two ID's that are the same?

Comment: You only want the query to return (at most) 1 ID number?

Comment: what do you mean by "the only smaller number"

Comment: the ID is not primary key so I want all next smallest records.

Comment: @AdamV:it will return the entire row

Comment: yeah sure the table has three columns ID, NodeName and NodeType

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`WITH TIES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)  clause:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
FROM mytable
WHERE ID < 4
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

`TOP` clause in conjunction with `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` selects the *next smallest* value to `4`. `WITH TIES` clause guarantees that *all* these values will be returned, in case there is more than one.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abb87/3)

Comment: A little explanation will be helpful

Comment: what does this ties do? can you please explain me?

Comment: @Rebecca It selects *all* top level rows in case of value equality, i.e. like in your case where there are 2 top level values equal to `2`.

Comment: @Rebecca is MSDN down?

Comment: @Frisbee: [Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos:Hi Sir, actually by using ties in my query I am only getting the lowest records i.e. records with "0" ID

Comment: @Rebecca Did you use `DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Got it, I was not using the DESC with order by. Now it is working fine:)

Comment: Thank you so much Sir:) I really appreciate your help:)

Comment: @AdamV MSDN is not down if MSDN goes permanently off line .NET is in serious trouble.  It is a spanking great answer with explanation, link, and Demo

Comment: @Frisbee: The answer was fine (once he added the explanation, per @HaveNoDisplayName). I was responding to your comment, which was overly terse and could be considered insulting.

Comment: @AdamV "is MSDN down?" is overly terse and insulting?   Comments are not for discussion but wow outstanding answer with demo.  And I like your edit.  I get you are just trying to make SO better.  I will take a short great answer any day.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ID
from dbo.yourtable
where ID in
(
    select top 1 ID
    from dbo.your_table
    where ID < 4
    order by ID desc
);
```

*Note: where `dbo.your_table` is your source table*

What this does it uses an inner query to pull the next smallest `ID` below your selected value.  Then the outer query just pulls all records that have that same match to the `ID` of the next smallest value.

Here's a full working example:

```
use TestDatabase;
go

create table dbo.TestTable1
(
    ID int not null
);
go

insert into dbo.TestTable1 (ID)
values (6), (4), (2), (2), (1), (0);
go

select ID
from dbo.TestTable1
where ID in
(
    select top 1 ID
    from dbo.TestTable1
    where ID < 4
    order by ID desc
);
/*
ID
2
2
*/
```

Comment: The top `select ID` should probably be `select *`, based on Rebecca's comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir:) This is also working fine:)